# How to split aggregated list into multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to create separate columns for each item in the 'name' lists for each row in this pandas dataframe.  The 'name' lists have between 1-10 items, and I just want the column heads to be "1", "2", "3", etc.

```
out = dataframe.groupby(by=['location'], as_index=False).agg({'people':'sum', 'name':list})
```

Is there a way to split the aggregated list like this?

This is my original dataframe:
[image: This is my original data frame]

This is the dataframe I want to have:
[image: This is what I want]

Comment: please provide a clear sample of the input data and the matching expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by two steps , `cumcount` with `pivot`

```
out1 = dataframe.groupby('location').agg({'people':'sum'})
out2 = dataframe.assign(key = dataframe.groupby('location').cumcount()).pivot('location', 'key', 'name')
out = out1.join(out2).reset_index()
```